# Test if String contains Letters and Characters

Tags: r

I got this vector:

```
bar <- c("aaa:something", "111:something", "a1a1:something", "1a:something")
```

I want to check whether before the colon (`:`) there are letters **and** numbers. It can be abitrarily many, but both need to be in there, so the result should be

```
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the numbers and letters will be in any order you can do :

```
grepl('([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+):', bar)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: OK, I get the idea, but it doesn't work in all cases. Can you revise the answer to `grepl('([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+):.*', bar)`? Right now it wouldn't work on `"1a"`.

Comment: sorry, I accidentally copied the same pattern twice I think. I edited the answer.

Comment: Guessed so. I actually edited the question to make the difference clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two `grepl` like:

```
grepl("[[:digit:]].*:", bar) & grepl("[[:alpha:]].*:", bar)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#grepl("[0-9].*:", bar) & grepl("[a-zA-Z].*:", bar) #Alternative
```

To *make it in one go* you can use a non consuming expression:

```
grepl("(?=.*[[:digit:]]).*[[:alpha:]].*:", bar, perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: That's true, but I actually need to do it in one go. Still a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
grepl("[a-z]+\\d+.*\\:|\\d+[a-z]+.*\\:", bar, ignore.case = TRUE)
```